# SQL syntax to spit on duplicate name

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need help.  I have been thinking about this for several nights now, but I can't get it right.

Context: On a table, I have 'referenceID' field and 'nameID' field. Each 'referenceID' field should only have the one 'nameID' assigned.

Ie:

```
record1: 'referenceID' field: 001 and 'nameID' field: 00a
record2: 'referenceID' field: 001 and 'nameID' field: 00a
record3: 'referenceID' field: 002 and 'nameID' field: 00b
record4: 'referenceID' field: 002 and 'nameID' field: 00c
```

Ask: What's the shortest SQL syntax statement to display 'referenceID' field and it's have corresponding  'nameID' if  'referenceID' has more than 1 'nameID'.

Correct output: record3 and record 4

```
'referenceID' field: 002 and 'nameID' field: 00b
'referenceID' field: 002 and 'nameID' field: 00c
```

Comment: It'd help if your sample data better represented the actual values ...or should the expected output really list the same "referenceID" twice?

Comment: Also, which dbms and version are you using?

Comment: The expected output should list the reference ID twice, so when it's imported, we can easily identify which referenceID has non unique nameID.  How do I know what version of Snowflake I am using? (sorry for asking stupid question.  My knowledge of SQL is basically select * from tablenamebut willing to elarn as it's so powerful).  Thank you.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Sample data is better presented as tables where the header row represents the column names from the table (pretty much like a SQL client would return/show the data). Currently it's unclear to me if you have  a single column that contains the string `'referenceID' field: 001 and 'nameID' field: 00a` or if those are two columns named `referenceID` and `nameID` that contain `'field 001'` and `'field 00a'`. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: @VIckie08: since you are using Snowflake, I added the tag `Snowflake....`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this query:

I assume your database name is: "test" and using mysql database.

```
SELECT
    T1.referenceID,
    T1.nameID
FROM
    test T1
    LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT 
    T3.referenceID,
    T3.nameID,
    COUNT(T3.referenceID) AS 'countrefID'
FROM

(SELECT 
    referenceID,
    nameID,
    COUNT(CONCAT(referenceID,nameID)) AS 'countuniqueID'
FROM
    test
GROUP BY
    referenceID, nameID
HAVING COUNT(CONCAT(referenceID,nameID)) = 1) T3

GROUP BY
    referenceID
HAVING COUNT(T3.referenceID) > 1) T2 ON T1.referenceID = T2.referenceID
WHERE
    T2.countrefID > 1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).